# Filter out matches below a given score in Elasticsearsch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement that seemed quite simple at first, however I've been banging my head against it for the last few days. I have an index containing customer data. The requirement is that when a new customer arrives, the program should look for that customer in the index. A result with a match above a specific percentage should be considered an exact duplicate while results with a lower match percentage (say 80-90%) should be marked as possible duplicates. As elasticsearch scoring is not normalized to an exact range (for example 0 to 1) I am not sure how to express the match percentage in the formula.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    POST _search
{

  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "fuzzy" : { "LAST_NAME" : "Hanks" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "FIRST_NAME" : "Tom" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "PHONE" : "0045123456" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "MAILING_CITY" : "Chicago" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "EMAIL" : "tom_hanks@email.com" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "WORK_PHONE" : "0045223344" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "MOBILE_PHONE" : "0045456789" }}
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 5
  }}}
```

Here is what I imagine to have: I want to give following fields a specific "weight" in the total match percentage:

- FIRST_NAME:1
- LAST_NAME, MAILING_CITY: 2
- PHONE,WORK_PHONE: 3
- EMAIL, MOBILE_PHONE: 4

Every record with the exact same values for every field would be an exact match with a score of 100%. Then, say I have a record where the LAST_NAME does not match. I imagine the score should be calculated as follows: 1 (FIRST_NAME weight) + 3(PHONE weight) + 2 (MAILING_CITY weight) + 4 (EMAIL weight)+ 3 (WORK_PHONE weight) + 4 (MOBILE_PHONE weight) / (2+1+3+2+4+3+4)= 89%

I know this is a very inaccurate approach for correctly identifying a duplicate customer but it would give me an approximate match score, which is what I need. The minimum_number_should_match clause would instantly filter out customers with less than 5 matching clauses and the match percentage should be calculated for all others. Is it possible to do this with elasticsearch? Any clue would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How do you "match" your customer exactly?

Comment: An exact match would be considered a record where all the fields in the query (first name, last name, phone number etc.) match. Such an entry would have a match percentage of 100%.

Comment: Ok, and what would make the record only match 80%? If the phone number is not present? If the first name is abbreviated (`Mike` instead of `Michael`)? Since many people can have the same first/last name, you need some kind of discriminating fields that would allow you to cast a vote with more certainty, right?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of adding boost clauses to specific fields such as email, phone number etc.. Apart from that I am using fuzzy queries so that customers won't be filtered out based on misspellings or alternative spellings of names. Also, the query is formed by multiple "should" clauses to prevent one different field to eliminate the customer from the record set completely (as obviously last names, phone numbers etc. can change). So far, I'm using the minimum_number_should_match to filter out records below a specific number of matches.

Comment: The next step is probably to show the query you have now and a sample document that should/not match

Comment: Here is what I have so far:

POST _search
{

  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        { "fuzzy" : { "LAST_NAME" : "Hanks" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "FIRST_NAME" : "Tom" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "PHONE" : "0045123456" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "MAILING_CITY" : "Chicago" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "EMAIL" : "tom_hanks@email.com" } },
     { "fuzzy" : { "WORK_PHONE" : "0045223344" } },
        { "fuzzy" : { "MOBILE_PHONE" : "0045456789" }}
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 5
  }}}

Comment: Here is what I imagine to have:
 I want to give following fields a specific "weight" in the total match percentage:
 FIRST_NAME:1
 LAST_NAME, MAILING_CITY: 2
 PHONE,WORK_PHONE: 3
 EMAIL, MOBILE_PHONE: 4

Comment: Every record with the exact same values for every field would be an exact match with a score of 100%.

 Then, say I have a record where the LAST_NAME does not match. I imagine the score should be calculated as follows:
 1 (FIRST_NAME weight) + 3(PHONE weight) + 2 (MAILING_CITY weight) + 4 (EMAIL weight)+ 3 (WORK_PHONE weight) + 4 (MOBILE_PHONE weight) / (2+1+3+2+4+3+4)= 89%

Comment: I know this is a very inaccurate approach for correctly identying a duplicate customer but it would give me an approximate match score, which is what I need.
 The minimum_number_should_match clause would instaltly filter out contacts with less than 5 matching clauses and the match percentage should be calculated for all others.
 Is it possible to do this with elasticsearch?
 Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You should really update your question with all that info and code, it's more legible

Comment: Thanks. I updated it :)

Comment: ...and properly format it, too :-) (=> help us help you)

Comment: Done. Hope it's fine now :)